# Initializing derived class enum with (unscoped) base class enum having the same name

Tags: c++, inheritance, enums

The following code (also on [ideone](http://ideone.com/VnGWt1)) looks like it shouldn't compile but it does on MSVC 2008 and GCC 4.8.2

```
#include<iostream>

struct Base
{
    enum State { ON = 11 , OFF = 22 , STANDBY = 33 };
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    enum State { ON = ON , OFF = OFF };  // Huh?
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << Derived::ON << std::endl;
}
```

Is it standard compliant?

Comment: Point of declaration of enum member is right after its initializer. So the `ON` after `=` is `Base::ON` - it hasn't been hidden yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
enum State { ON = ON , OFF = OFF };  // Huh?
                  ^^
```

At this point derived re-definition is not complete, so ON used would be from Base.